# How to get sub-menus to drop down left?

Tags: html, css

The following code is from a wordpress theme CSS file that I am working on. Submenus used to appear to the right of the parent but I added in "left: 0;" in the first block of css code and now it aligns it self with the left side of the parent menu (and so sits on top of the drop down).

How can I alter the code so the submenus appear to the left of the parent?

```
/* =DROP DOWN
----------------------------------------------- */
.main-navigation ul li ul,
.main-navigation ul li:hover ul ul,
.main-navigation ul ul li:hover ul ul,
.main-navigation ul ul ul li:hover ul ul,
.main-navigation ul ul ul ul li:hover ul ul {
    display: none;
        left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover ul,
.main-navigation ul ul li:hover ul,
.main-navigation ul ul ul li:hover ul,
.main-navigation ul ul ul ul li:hover ul,
.main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
.main-navigation ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border-top: 1px solid #0FBE7C;
    top: 45px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 150px;
}
.main-navigation ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul li ul li a,
.main-navigation ul li.current-menu-item ul li a,
.main-navigation ul li ul li.current-menu-item a,
.main-navigation ul li.current_page_ancestor ul li a,
.main-navigation ul li.current-menu-ancestor ul li a,
.main-navigation ul li.current_page_item ul li a {
    float: none;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    color: #666666;
}
.main-navigation ul li ul li a:hover, .main-navigation ul li ul li:hover > a, .main-navigation ul li.current-menu-item ul li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    color: #0FBE7C;
}
.main-navigation ul li ul li ul {
    left: 150px;
    top: -1px;
}
.main-navigation select {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `right: 0` instead of `left: 0;`

Now the right side of the sub-menu will be aligned to the parent.

Comment: For me, when I changed the code like you said, it simply sends the sub-menu off to the right. Could there be any other code in the snippet given stopping your suggestion working?

Comment: Really struggling with this one Johannes - could you take another look?

Comment: It would be necessary to exmine the actual page with the developer tools to see what CSS rules/properties apply to the parent element

Comment: Thanks Johannes. I got it working by adding "right:100%;" and "left:auto;". Many thanks for your time.

Comment: uhhh - that was my mistake - of course it has to be `right: 100%`, so that it aligns to the *left* side of the parent - sorry, didn't think it to the end (if I'd had a chance to try it, I would have seen my error). However, `left: auto`is  unnecessary and can be erased.